# How do I move my folders created by CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

CMake uses absolute paths when it generates project files for Visual C++.

Sometimes, I need to move my project folder to some other drive.

But when I move the folder (and try to replace all the paths in the project files), this triggers a long, arduous recompilation process that wastes a lot of my time for absolutely no reason.

How do I move CMake project folder(s) to an arbitrary location **without** triggering a recompilation?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of [CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS) var:

> In general, it is not possible to move CMake generated makefiles to a different location regardless of the value of this variable.

Comment: Actually this variable works great for Visual Studio generators (at least VS 2008 and 2010)

Comment: Official documentation `Use relative paths (May not work!)`. C++ is brilliant!

Comment: C++ has nothing to do with this, it is more CMake related (or even generator used). Anyways, starting from CMake 3.5 this variable has no effect at all.