# How to tell CMake to use relative paths

Tags: cmake

If I make my project I can see this:

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj
/cygdrive/c/users/me/Home/bin/iccarm  /cygdrive/c/users/me/Home/sandbox/iar/hello.c  -I/cygdrive/c/users/me/Home/sandbox/iar/foo -I/cygdrive/c/users/me/Home/inc   -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj
```

Since I always call `make` inside my `build` directory, why not using relative path for the sake of readability and compatibility across operating systems?

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj
iccarm  hello.c -Ifoo -Iinc -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/hello.c.obj
```

Is it much better isn't it?

Is there a way to force CMake to use relative paths as much as possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CMake does always use absolute paths. It's part of the concept. Therefore you can't move the generated build environment files nor can you e.g. bring them under source control or make the verbose output prettier (you could just play a little with the rule messages like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903193/cmake-dont-print-directory-when-compiling-process)).

There once was [`CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS.html), but the documentation reveals:

> This variable has no effect. The partially implemented effect it had in previous releases was removed in CMake 3.4.

**References**

- [CMake FAQ: Why does CMake use full paths, or can I copy my build tree?](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Why_does_CMake_use_full_paths.2C_or_can_I_copy_my_build_tree.3F)
- [How do I move my folders created by CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225857/how-do-i-move-my-folders-created-by-cmake)

Comment: So it means `CMake` will not work properly on Cygwin. That a very sad news. I am wondering why they removed `CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS` it was just perfect...

Comment: @nowox Cygwin only works with the `cygwin` version of CMake. It will not work with the Windows version. And I think it was removed because it caused so many issues (CMake bugtracker was full of it).

Comment: which was removed? The windows version or the Cygwin version? The main issue with absolute paths is that if you use a tool chain built for Windows, the compiler is expecting windows paths. It works with Cygwin as long as the paths are relative but once you get absolute paths you have to write a bind script that replace the ugly /cygwin/c/ things with C:\... I would be nice if CMake had an option to do this on the fly

Comment: @nowox Sorry, I meant the `CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS` variable was removed because it had to many issues.

Comment: Well, having absolute paths is right pain to me. I can't move my source directory? How is that an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

CMakes gets the paths from the [CMake generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#id7). Using other generators like `Ninja`, produces *relative* paths by default.

You can use the `-G` option while running the cmake generation command. Example:

```
cmake .... -G Ninja
```

You can also [export compile commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html#variable:CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS) which will be useful in navigating your files in most editors.