# CMake Move project folder to another computer

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build a CEF project, which has proper Cmake scripts to generate the needed solution and project files. This compiles fine, but I need to share the resulting project with other users. I can't tell them to simply dowload CEF and run Cmake, since I added a lot of code on my own. How can I send my folder to them and have Cmake "rebuild" all project files in such a way that the paths work on their filesystem and still all my own files are still properly included ?

I could tell them to find/replace C:\project\path\on\my\computer\ to Y:\project\path\on\their\machine but that is very cumbersome. Also, Cmake uses forward and backward slashes at random seemingly...

Comment: I don't understand the question, what exactly are you sending? If you first build, then send the entire project folder, then yes, that would screw things up (assuming your build output is within that project folder) since you are also sending the CMake cache files. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: sorry if unclear: basically I want to compile a CEF-derived project on 2 computers where paths are different. I tried to make my own small application using the CEFsimple project with CMake, but that contains only absolute paths which won't work after porting to another machine with different filesystem layout.
I now have two options : 
- new project without cmake (or try to edit the proj file) but I can't get that to work :-(
- find a way to re-run CMake to "adjust" the paths. I don't know if this is feasible ?

What's the best to compile CMake-generated proj on 2 different paths ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell CMake to use relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856955/how-to-tell-cmake-to-use-relative-paths)